# Supercomputer Configuration

Tags: parallel-computing

I think I understand how supercomputers work in general, but I would like to know how they are configured. It seems to me that supercomputers  have a separate computers at each node, each with it's own processor, memory, storage, networking and operating system. It's all that really necessary? Why isn't each node given a processor and memory and a way to communicate with a master node, which is a real computer. Each with be provided with binary ready to run. Why does each node need to be able to run it to own operating system.

Comment: Your proposed architecture is called a *star* configuration and has been used on some older commercial machines. The disadvantage is that the central node is a bottleneck in that all node-to-node communications have to go through the central hub, limiting the communications to be serial. Other connection topologies don't suffer this problem, allowing nodes A and B to communicate at the same time as nodes C and D.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty hard to come up with a specific definition of a supercomputer. From what you described I think you have clusters in mind, which is basically a network of computers with some task-division possibilities. Every node in a cluster is a computer itself and they might (or should) communicate with each other.

I think your question indicates a slight lack of understanding what computers are and what operating systems do (what do you mean by *real computer*?) If you have a processor and a memory you need some operating system to use them effectively. For example, you mentioned "a way to communicate" between machines - that is pretty tough to implement reasonably without an operating system.

I would recommend checking [wikipedia page on computer clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) and taking it from there.